# In Gtk3 C, while connected to "key-release-event" how to avoid initial Return pressed to run the application

Tags: c, gtk3

Edit: I have found a solution for the simple example below, but it fails for my real application, and generates a critical warning on the example below. Through trial and error, I discovered that inserting `gtk_main_quit ()` at the end of the `activate` function successfully blocks the initial command line "Return". However, of course, it also generates a critical warning: `Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_main_quit: assertion 'main_loops != NULL' failed`. Another thing that works for the example but I don't want in my application is to put up a "hello" dialog in the `activate` function which the user has to dismiss.

I am working on a Gtk3 app that listens for the key-release-event, and I would like one of those events to be the "Return" key. The app will normally be started from a .desktop file, but may be started from a terminal too. When started from a terminal, it recognizes the initial "Return"  that the user pressed to execute the app as a key-press. How can I avoid that? Here is a simple example "test_return.c"

```
/* gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` -o test_return test_return.c `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`
 */
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static gboolean key_event_cb (GtkWidget *widget,
                            GdkEventKey *event,
                                gpointer data)
{
  if (event->keyval == GDK_KEY_Return) {
    GtkWidget *dialog = 
      gtk_message_dialog_new (GTK_WINDOW(widget), 
          GTK_DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT, 
          GTK_MESSAGE_INFO, GTK_BUTTONS_CLOSE, 
          "Return");
    gtk_dialog_run (GTK_DIALOG (dialog));
    gtk_widget_destroy (dialog);
    return TRUE;
  }
  return FALSE; //allow further processing of the keypress if it's not Return
}

static void activate (GtkApplication* app,
                      gpointer        user_data)
{  
  GtkWidget *window;

  window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
  gtk_widget_show_all (window);
  g_signal_connect (window, "key-release-event", 
                    G_CALLBACK (key_event_cb), NULL); //keyboard events
}

int
main (int    argc,
      char **argv)
{
  GtkApplication *app;
  int status;

  app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
  g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
  status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), 0, NULL);
  g_object_unref (app);

  return status;
}
```

What I want to happen is that it will not pop up a dialog until "Return" is pressed. When run from a terminal, it immediately shows the dialog because it recognizes the "Return" pressed in the terminal to start the app. When run from a .desktop file, it works as expected.

At first, I tried simply defining a gboolean that was TRUE at start, and FALSE after the first Return. That worked from the terminal, but then requred 2 Return key-presses when started from a .desktop file. My app will only be used in Linux (and in fact requires X11). I tried `fflush(stdin);`, but it doesn't work. I even tried a timer to ignore Returns received in the first hundreth of a second using https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Timers.html, but I get strange behavior.

From the comments, I remembered that I've already tried waiting to connect the signal until the widget is fully drawn. It didn't work. Apparently, the "Return" key press is waiting in a buffer, but I can't figure out how to clear that buffer.

Also from the comments, I remembered that I already tried getchar() but that just waited for a character to be entered, completely ignoring the Return that I was trying to get rid of.

I edited main() replacing argc, argv with 0, NULL in the g_application_run funtion to ignore command line arguments, but that didn't help.

Comment: Have you considered just consuming the first key release event the application sees when the indicated key is the return key?  Or consuming such events that arrive within some short time of application startup?  These are a bit hacky, but they ought to get the job done.

Comment: How about watching for some other event, and using that to turn on the key-watching event? For example, you could watch for "Window Mapped" or "Refresh" (I'm not a GTK programmer, but there must be events like that).  Once you see "Window Mapped," you know that the program is up and running, and would want to process any subsequent Return key-ups.

Comment: Perhaps you can move the goal posts and use a different key.

Comment: How to consume it? I tried fflush(stdin) and also tried a single getchar() as a test, and it didn't consume the Return. Instead, it waited for me to enter a character. As mentioned in my question, I also tried waiting a hundredth of a second. This worked from the terminal, but caused strange behavior from a .desktop file which I haven't been able to debug.

Comment: @Dave M., I forgot until you mentioned it that my very first idea was just what you say. I didn't connect the signal until the widget was fully drawn. I did this in the widget's draw callback function. It made no difference. The Return from the command line was still there.

Comment: @WeatherVane, In order to move on with development, I did change the key to F4, which works great (I'm already using F1 through F3). But, I really want to use Return.

Comment: Can you flush the input event queue after you see the "window mapped" event?  (The reason flushing stdin doesn't work is that stdin doesn't use the GTK event queue.  Stdio-using programs don't need both key-down and key-up events, and most don't even care about key-pressed; they only want input after it's been line-edited by the pseudo-tty.  And even key-oriented programs like `vi` don't use key-down/key-up.)

Comment: @DaveM. Since you explain that fflush(stdin) can't work, what exactly are you suggesting I do once the window is mapped? What specific code do I use to flush the input event queue?

Comment: After a little poking around `developer.gnome.org`, I'd guess you want to drain the event queue after `gtk_widget_show_all` and before `g_signal_connect`.  I think you can do it by calling `gtk_main_iteration_do(FALSE)` until it returns `FALSE`.  Then do `g_signal_connect`.

Comment: Have you tested it? Actually we both posted at the same time. I came up with a solution. See my answer below. I discovered the terminal Return doesn't have a key-press-event , only a key-release-event; so it can be distinguished from the other Returns since they all have a key-press-event.

Comment: Sorry, that's not quite right.  (I also don't really understand what your program is supposed to do, or how to set it up to run from a desktop shortcut.)  When I run it from the command line, I get a blank window.  When I type return in that window, I get a [Return/Close] dialog, but Close doesn't close the window.

Comment: Very nice!  I don't know why I'm not seeing the key release when I run the program; it must be a difference between our shells or gnome-terminal or something.  Anyway, glad you've gotten it figured out.

Comment: @DaveM. The example is doing what it should for you, except it should close the dialog when you click close. I don't know why that would fail. Also, for you, the terminal Return that's causing all my trouble isn't causing you the same trouble. Thanks for working on it for me though.

Comment: Ah, I see, it just closes the dialog, and if you type return again, it opens.  I thought the whole app would close.

Answer (score 2):

As I was reading through all the GdkEvent functions: https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Events.html, I eventually realized it might be informative to use `gdk_set_show_events (TRUE)` so that as the program runs, all the events are listed in the terminal. There were tons of events, but just searching on the word "key" I eventually realized something very important. There is a difference between the Return key event from the command line and all the other Return key events: the one from the command line doesn't have a key-press-event, only a key-release event! So, here's how the solution works for the example shown in my question:

```
/* gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` -o test_return test_return.c `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`
 */
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

// Need to keep track of both key press and key release to distinguish unwanted terminal Return from others.
// The terminal Return that started the app won't have a key press event.
static gboolean key_press_event_cb (GtkWidget *widget,
                            GdkEventKey *event,
                                gpointer data)
{
  gboolean *p_key_pressed = data;
  *p_key_pressed = TRUE;
  return FALSE; //keep processing event
}

static gboolean key_release_event_cb (GtkWidget *widget,
                            GdkEventKey *event,
                                gpointer data)
{
  gboolean *p_key_pressed = data;
  // If there's no key-press before this key-release, then it's from starting the app in a terminal
  // So ignore it.
  if (*p_key_pressed & event->keyval == GDK_KEY_Return) {
    GtkWidget *dialog = 
      gtk_message_dialog_new (GTK_WINDOW(widget), 
          GTK_DIALOG_DESTROY_WITH_PARENT, 
          GTK_MESSAGE_INFO, GTK_BUTTONS_CLOSE, 
          "time is %d", event->time);
    gtk_dialog_run (GTK_DIALOG (dialog));
    gtk_widget_destroy (dialog);
    return TRUE;
  }
  return FALSE; //allow further processing of the keypress if it's not Return
}

static void activate (GtkApplication* app,
                      gpointer        user_data)
{  
  GtkWidget *window;
  // create a pointer to a gboolean to track the key press events
  static gboolean key_pressed = FALSE, *p_key_pressed = &key_pressed;

  window = gtk_application_window_new (app);

  g_signal_connect (window, "key-press-event", 
                    G_CALLBACK (key_press_event_cb), p_key_pressed); // p_key_pressed will be the "data" in cb function
  g_signal_connect (window, "key-release-event", 
                    G_CALLBACK (key_release_event_cb), p_key_pressed); // p_key_pressed will be the "data" in cb function

  gtk_widget_show_all (window);
}

int
main (int    argc,
      char **argv)
{
  GtkApplication *app;
  int status;

  app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
  g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
  status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), 0, NULL);
  g_object_unref (app);

  return status;
}
```